# How do I install 2 different versions of java on the same machine from EPEL

Tags: linux, java, epel

Title says it all. I want to have 2 versions of java on the same machine. For example `14.0.1.7` and `14.0.2.12` (which are both in EPEL7 repo).

If i install them one by one via `yum`, yum will remove first version and keep just the last. If I install them via `rpm` dependencies are resolved but not installed automatically. If i install first with `yum` and second with `rpm` then it works and it keeps both versions but `rpm` won't install any additional dependencies if the pop out at some point and it would be cool to be able to do it via only one tool.

All mentioned java are OpenJDK; EPEL7 has these rolling packages (for example: `java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64`, `java-14-openjdk-14.0.2.12-1.rolling.el7.x86_64`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Upgrade to the later package, which has fixes.

`java-latest-openjdk` `14.0.2.12-1` replaces `14.0.1.7-2`. EPEL mirrors won't carry the old version, as is their usual policy.

The [upstream release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/14-0-2-relnotes.html) say the security patched version of 14 is `14.0.2+12`. Note the usual time zone data and x509 cert changes, plus bug fixes. Think about whether you really need to pin this version. The documentation indicates this to be a minor maintenance release you are intended to take.

If you identify a need to keep the previous version, two problems to resolve: getting the package and installing it. The old version is no longer on the mirrors, consider setting up your own private mirror or caching proxy to archive old versions. And, these two versions cannot be installed in parallel. Investigate a way to have two parallel environments, whether containers, virtual machines, or runtime manager utilities which specifically allow you to select a Java runtime.

Comment: Yeah after a lot of trying i guess this is correct what you say. It's not possible with just yum and way packages are arranged currently. I guess runtime manager is quickest solution without having to introduce containers into the env.

Comment: You are missing my main point: this isn't about containers or environment wrappers. Everything requires updates, and Java regularly due to how it handles certs and tzdata. Study your applications and come up with a good reason why you need to spend effort standing up an environment with an old version. Default to don't bother and just upgrade it.

Comment: I understand completely the main point. What I was searching was a quick way to have 2 minor versions of same packet. I could go into details but didn't want to complicate the question and go in exactly this direction. I'm aware of the need to redesign. However current setup requires us to test different minor versions on same Java for various reasons. This is legacy setup and done when it was possible (with Oracle Java 8).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Use a java runtime manager such as [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) or [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/)

Long answer: By default, package managers are trying to help keep up to date with the latest version of the packages in your system. This is why it is common to find alternative package managers like the above for different languages (pyenv or conda for python, nvm for node/js, etc).

You mention this is for EPEL which might mean you are restricted on the internet access. This might be an issue. In general though these alt package managers are installed in the user session and the environment variables controlled affect only the current user. This might be an advantage or disadvantage depending on what exactly you are working on.

Without more information I think using the existing tools mentioned above (btw there might be newer ones) might be a good place to start. Feel free to add more info if needed and good luck!

Comment: Thanx for the input. I'll check sdkman. There is also jabba but i don't find JREs on its default list. Just JDKs.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the primary use-cases for Docker, in which a container can contain differing supporting libraries and/or differing application versions in their own isolated environments without the overhead and complexity of virtualization.

In the simplest Dockerfile, once could source a CentOS or RHEL base image, add repositories, and install the packages you want.

It matters what the use-case is here, and if the goal can be expressed via containers. In most cases, it can be. Here's an example dockerfile:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64

ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [run.sh]
```

That last block is almost entirely made up, but is valid. If you can express your application as a microservice, this docker-based solution can make a lot of sense.

Otherwise, you can accomplish similar results with an LXD container, with the exception that you can expose an entire IP (much like a VM). You could also use a VM. Both are more complex than a docker based solution that exposes a single IP/port combination per application.

Comment: I absolutely agree for the Docker solution but sometimes (as this is the case) it's not possible to use it due to this or that restrictions.

Answer (score -2):

Check This post, Redhat web

https://access.redhat.com/node/3040171

Regards.

Comment: This post is useless without the relevant information being included, as that link is not accessible to everyone.